# mongodb update document at given time intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm implementing a "lowest bid auction" system. The users will set a base price, a price drop amount and a price drop interval. For example if an user set base price = 1000$ , price drop amount = 100$ , price drop interval = 1 hour, after 3 hours the price will be 700$, after 3.2 hours the price will still be 700$, after 4 hours it will be 600$...

These prices are stored into a mongodb database and need to be queried, so calculating current prices in node.js after the database querying gets really expensive. Is there a way to tell mongodb to update each document at a given time interval? Should I implement a node.js microservice that keep track of all these timers, and updates the documents when needed?
In practice these times will be actually big ( hours usually ), but I want to keep track of a lot of them.

Thank You,
Matteo

Answer (score 4):

If you're using nodejs you could use Agenda to do this: https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda

so you'd define a task to reduce the prices of all your items:

```
var mongoConnectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/agenda";
var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: mongoConnectionString}});

agenda.define('reduce prices', {priority: 'high', concurrency: 1}, function(job, done) {
  // .. do your db query to reduce the price here
  done(); // dont forget to call done!
});
```

and then invoke it once an hour:

```
agenda.on('ready', function() {
  agenda.every('60 minutes', 'reduce prices');
  agenda.start();
});
```

And that's it. If you're using express and put this in your express app then you don't need to run a separate cron task - however this query will run on the same process as the rest of your application, so depending on how many "product" objects you're reducing prices for, this may or may not be an issue.